# Issue with State Variables not being recognised within a promise

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I have this piece of code below in React, it is in a Parent Component. Basically what it is supposed to do is for every row, it shows a child component and creates a promise. The child component allows the user to change the data and then press submit which uses a callback function to update the `submitPressedOnEvent` state variable in the parent using `SetSubmitPressedOnEvent(true).`

```
    const processRowsAsync = async (rows: any[]) => {

        // Iterate over the array of rows
        for (const row of rows) {

            console.log("Processing Next Row: " + submitPressedOnEvent);

            // Set the current line data
            setCurrentLineData({ ...row, category: "" });
            console.log("Set Curent Line Data: " + submitPressedOnEvent);

            setShowEventDialog(true);
            console.log("Showed Event Dialog: " + submitPressedOnEvent);

            // Wait for the user to click the Submit button
            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                console.log("Creating Promise: " + submitPressedOnEvent);

                const interval = setInterval(() => {

                    console.log("Interval : " + submitPressedOnEvent);
                    if (submitPressedOnEvent) {
                        console.log("Fulfilled Promise: " + submitPressedOnEvent);

                        setSubmitPressedOnEvent(false);
                        console.log("Set Pressed Event to False: " + submitPressedOnEvent);

                        clearInterval(interval);
                        resolve(null);

                        console.log("Resolved Promise: " + submitPressedOnEvent);
                    }
                }, 500);
            });

            // Output the selected category to the console
            console.log("Selected Category: " + currentLineData?.category + " : " + submitPressedOnEvent);
        }
    };
```

thanks for any assistance.

The above all works well and i can see in the parent component that the `submitPressedOnEvent` value is true. However when it gets to the promise to check if the state variable `submitPressedOnEvent` is true it is false.

The wierd thing is that if i put a breakpoint just after `SetSubmitPressedOnEvent(true) in the handlesubmit callback function`, i can hover over `if (submitPressedOnEvent)` in the promise function and can see it is set to true, but when it actually gets to that line of code in the promise function it is false again.

It seems to be resetting to the initial value of that state variable.

Comment: Please include the definition of `submitPressedOnEvent` in your code. I bet it's not actually a *var*iable but rather a `const`ant, and you're using a react function component for state handling?

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for replying, much appreciated. 

You are 100% correct. The setting is a constant, not a variable. That was very misleading and i apologise for that. 

In addition yes i am using a react function component for state handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the classic "stale closure" react problem where the interval callback only can observe the state at the time when it was started, but not the state from any later render. You *could* solve this by using a ref, but a much better solution is not to use an interval that polls for the boolean state at all. Instead, resolve the promise from  the click handler!

```
// remove those:
// const [currentLineData, setCurrentLineData] = useState();
// const [showEventDialog, setShowEventDialog] = useState(false);
// instead use:
const [eventDialog, setEventDialog] = useState(null);

const processRowsAsync = async (rows: any[]) => {
    for (const row of rows) {
        // setCurrentLineData({ ...row, category: "" });
        // setShowEventDialog(true);

        // Wait for the user to click the Submit button
        const category = await new Promise((resolve) => {
            // open the dialog and pass the submit handler:
            setEventDialog({ row, onSubmit: resolve });
 //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        });

        // Output the selected category to the console
        console.log("Selected Category: " + category);
    }
};

// if (showEventDialog) {
if (eventDialog != null) {
    return <EventDialog
        // row={currentLineData}
        row={eventDialog.row}
        onSubmit={chosenCategory => {
            // currentLineData.category = choseCategory; // ugly mutation - avoid!
            // setShowEventDialog(false); // not working

            eventDialog.onSubmit(chosenCategory);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            setEventDialog(null); // close it
        }}
    />
}
```

(I'm guessing here at your current code)

You can also simplify to `<EventDialog {...eventDialog} />` and doing the `setEventDialog(null);` after the `await new Promise(…)` from the processing task.